# Authorization Server Endpoints

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0, oauth-1.0a

As we know the **Spring Security OAuth 2.0** project has bee **depreciated** and now it's Spring Security 5.

My question is related with **Authorisation Server** for grant_type: `authorization_code`. Spring team is also working on standalone project for [Authorization Server](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server). So most of the codebase in Spring Security project is depreciated for Authorization Server.

Still, I've couple of questions for endpoints with `authorization_code` flow in Spring Security 2.0/5.

**OAuth 2.0:**

Can you please let me know, which endpoints are supported for below use cases in `Authorization Flow`:

1. Login Button: ask the customised authorization url from `Authorization Server`.
2. User logged-in: once **end-user** logged-in (authenticate), need to `authorise` with registered **client application** and provide the `code` in the callback URI.
3. Request For Access Token: once the `code` has been received in previous step, it should use the `code` to get the `access token`.

Please let me know which endpoints are meant to be used in Spring Security OAuth 2.0/5 for above use cases. Based on my research, I've found these endpoints:

1. [/oauth/token](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/TokenEndpoint.html): get the access token
2. [/oauth/token_key](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/TokenKeyEndpoint.html): produces JWT encoded token values
3. [/oauth/check_token](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/CheckTokenEndpoint.html): validate the access token

Can you please let me know which endpoint dedicated for authorisation **before** end-user authenticate in **use case #1**. And **after** end-user authentication in **use case #2**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many Thanks,
Adnan